# How to create 2 separate list<string> from a given text file in c#

Tags: c#

I've been given a text file. The details on the text file are mentioned below

> ab|123456 receptor 0M9C[some name]
>   ABRAKADABRATDNPQLQVVIFSAAAAAAAAAABHDBSIISLTLLDSAMNJHDFBHGFBNFBHGHFBNVCN
>   AGHDGBEBEHGFNMFIFLGSTEFFLLASMSYDCYVAICKPLHYTTIMSDRICYQLIISSWLAGFLVIFPPLAM
>   ab|145678 receptor 00AB[some name]NABSNBFBFGBFNBNBNBFJHBFNBFNBJHJBFNBFVIIHSDSHLHTPMYFFLSNLSLVDLGYSSAVAPKTV
>   AALRSGDKAISYDGCAAQFFFFVGFATVECYLLASMAYDRHAAVCRPLHYTTTMTAGVCALLATGSYVSG
>   ab|137565 receptor 0D0 [some name]
>   MKNKSMEIEFILLGLTDDPQLQIVIFLFLFLNYTLSLMGNLIIIILTLLDPRLKTPMYFFLRNFSFLEVIFTTVCIP
>   KJKDHDNDJFNFNNBFNBFBNBFBJBNFJNFJFGVALLYTSIAPLLNPFIYTLRNQQVKEVFWDVLQKNLCFSKRPF

I've to create to 2 List,

1st List name (the lines with [some name])
2nd List unique_code( the lines with all capital letter)

The name and unique code are related to each other.

I was able to get the name from the text file using the below code

```
List<string> Name = new List<string>();
System.IO.StreamReader file =new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);


var query = from line in File.ReadLines(filename)           //linq query to select the name
            where line.Contains("some name")
            select line;


        foreach (string line in query)                      //storing the name in a list
        {
            Name.Add(line);

        }
```

Can anyone please suggest how to get the second list for the unique code.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: can you share your text file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
List<List<string>> lists = File.ReadLines("Path")
    .GroupBy(l => l.Contains("[some name]"))
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

If the name-lines are related to the other lines i would suggest to use a custom class instead. That makes your code much more readable and maintainable.

Here is an example class:

```
public class Receptor
{
    public Receptor(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Codes = new List<string>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Codes { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the loop i would use:

```
List<Receptor> receptors = new List<Receptor>();
var lines = File.ReadLines("Path").SkipWhile(l => !l.Contains("[some name]"));

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (line.Contains("[some name]"))
        receptors.Add(new Receptor(line));
    else
        receptors.Last().Codes.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what index in the `List<List<string>>` would the lines be which did contain `[some name]`?

Comment: First the lines which contain `[some name]`. But just because the first line contained `[some name]`. If you want it to be more explicit you could append `.OrderBy(g => g.Key ? 0 : 1)` after the `GroupBy`.

Comment: would this also catch that second `[some name]` which includes a line break?

Comment: @Default: no, it's just looking at the lines. If that's not desired it's not the right approach. But OP always mentioned _lines_.

Comment: @Neel: i have tested it before i've posted it. So it works for me. If it doesn't give you the desired result you have to specify your requirements. You haven't even told what you expect.

Comment: ab|123456 receptor 0M9C[some name] ABRAKADABRATDNPQLQVVIFSAAAAAAAAAABHDBSIISLTLLDSAMNJHDFBHGFBNFBHGHFBNVCN AGHDGBEBEHGFNMFIFLGSTEFFLLASMSYDCYVAICKPLHYTTIMSDRICYQLIISSWLAGFLVIFPPLAM ab|145678 receptor 00AB[some name]NABSNBFBFGBFNBNBNBFJHBFNBFNBJHJBFNBFVIIHSDSHLHTPMYFFLSNLSLVDLGYSSAVAPKTV AALRSGDKAISYDGCAAQFFFFVGFATVECYLLASMAYDRHAAVCRPLHYTTTMTAGVCALLATGSYVSG ab|137565 receptor 0D0 [some name] MKNKSMEIEFILLGLTDDPQLQIVIFLFLFLNYTLSLMGNLIIIILTLLDPRLKTPMYFFLRNFSFLEVIFTTVCIP KJKDHDNDJFNFNNBFNBFBNBFBJBNFJNFJFGVALLYTSIAPLLNPFIYTLRNQQVKEVFWDVLQKNLCFSKRPF

Comment: above is result what it gives when I run you code in VS @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Neel: sorry, you have lost me. My code creates a list with two `List<string>`, i have no idea why you get a single string. That's not possible since it's declared as `List<List<string>>`. Maybe you haven't used a text-file as input but a string without line breaks.

Comment: may be coz of any of my copy paste issue in text file @TimSchmelter

Comment: bingo I jst asked the same thing and u said in ur edit of ur comment..i guess that's the reason @TimSchmelter

Comment: @TimSchmelter, if I've to print the unique code using your code....how should I do it

Comment: btw I have used text file as input but its in one line in tht file @TimSchmelter

Comment: its working now my mistakes in copy pasting @TimSchmelter

Comment: then that is the reason. If you have one line you get only one line out. @dexter: what is the _unique code_?

Comment: name = ab|123456 receptor 0M9C[some name]

Comment: unique code = ABRAKADABRATDNPQLQVVIFSAAAAAAAAAABHDBSIISLTLLDSAMNJHDFBHGFBNFBHGHFBNVCN AGHDGBEBEHGFNMFIFLGSTEFFLLASMSYDCYVAICKPLHYTTIMSDRICYQLIISSWLAGFLVIFPPLAM

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Neel , I think there is a confusion, don't copy paste the data to a text file...it will come in a single line...the format of my text file is the same as I've mentioned in the question

Comment: @dexter: so every name belongs to the lines below until the next name?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, how should I do it using the Dictionary<string, List<string>>...you are right...name is the key  and the value is the list of lines which belong to this name( the lines from this name until the next)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, yes... name belongs to the lines below until the next name

Comment: @dexter: i would use a custom class. I have edited my answer to provide an example.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, pls tell me, the working of foreach loop.

Comment: @dexter: what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, receptors.Add(new Receptor(line)) this line is adding the name to the variable name in the receiptor 
and receptors.Last().Codes.Add(line) this line is adding the lines following the name to the Codes in the receiptor ...is it correct, or i'm wrong....Sorry I'm new to programming so I've little bit problem in understanding the code

Comment: If the line contains _your name_ a new `Receptor` object is instantiated and added to the `List<Receptor>` with the name in the line (maybe you need to use `Substring` to extract only the relevant part of the line). All other lines that follow it will be added to the `Codes` property(which is a `List<string>`) of the last receptor object in the list which is the current object since objects are added at the end in a list.

Answer (score 0):

for second list, for each line you can use a regex that search if all characters are uppercase

```
List<String> list = new List<string>();
string pattern = @"^[^a-z]+$";
foreach (string line in query)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.None);
    Match match = r.Match(line);
    if (match.Value != "")
        list.Add(match.Value);
   }
```

Comment: i have modified the regex for include all non alphabetic characters

Comment: I tried this code, but I'm getting a blank console with no output, can you pls explain the line(match.Value != "")

Comment: in your example you have already a foreach statement. add before the lines code for declare pattern and list.
Match use the regex expression and apply the rule of pattern to string. if there is no match(match.Value!=""), it would be that don't exist character from a to z. than add into list the value.
test if list contains string